# how can I remove 0 index key from my result in php?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [aid] => 1
                    [address] => Surat
                    [country] => India
                    [state] => Gujarat
                    [city] => Surat
                    [pincode] => 395010
                    [full_name] => Pra test
                    [mobile_no] => 7984509142
                    [email] => 
                    [default] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

I want response like:

```
Array
(
     [1] => Array
         (
             [aid] => 1
             [address] => Surat
             [country] => India
             [state] => Gujarat
             [city] => Surat
             [pincode] => 395010
             [full_name] => Pra test
             [mobile_no] => 7984509142
             [email] => 
             [default] => 0
         )
)
```

I want to remove 0 index from my response. I want my response like what I define below. so how can I do this with functions and etc..

Comment: Just make a new array and only copy the relevant item into it

Comment: for example $arr = $arr[0];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to remove an extra layer from a multi-dimentional array.

An easy way would be something like:

```
$new_array = $old_array[0];
```

Edit:

Per @Gert B's suggestion:
To return the first element regardless of the key:

```
$new_array = reset($old_array);
```

The reset function returns the pointer to the beginning of the array, and more importantly for this question, returns the first element of the array.

Comment: I would personally use `$new_array = reset($old_array);` to return the first element. just in case the key ever changes, it will still grab the first array key.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $old_array[0];
```

This was the easiest way ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$data = 'YOUR_DATA_ARRAY';
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $category => $attributes) {
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $result[] = array('category' => $category, 'attribute' => $attribute, 'option' => $option);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use array_replace_recursive() function and get response I want.

now my response is :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [aid] => 1
            [address] => Surat
            [country] => India
            [state] => Gujarat
            [city] => Surat
            [pincode] => 395010
            [full_name] => Pra test
            [mobile_no] => 7984509142
            [email] => 
            [default] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [aid] => 2
            [address] => Surat
            [country] => India
            [state] => Gujarat
            [city] => Surat
            [pincode] => 395010
            [full_name] => Pra test
            [mobile_no] => 7984509142
            [email] => 
            [default] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: I think instead sharing the output directly, you should share that how to use the `array_replace_recursion` function to get the desired output.